# Using repeated sampling to increase power

Tags: anova, sampling, repeated-measures

I want to determine if there is a difference in the proportion of transactions that include purchase a product (say paper) between stores in different countries.

I have:

- Store A (Australia): 37%
- Store B (Australia): 36%
- Store C (Canada): 34%
- Store D (USA): 36%
- etc.

My assumption would be to do a simple ANOVA comparing the mean percentage of transaction that include paper at stores, between countries.

The problem is, despite having very granular transactional data - each country only has a handful of stores.  I could increase the number of samples, by comparing store and month:

- Store A - January: 37%
- Store A - February: 35%
- etc.

I know that the % of sales that include paper would vary throughout the year, and I'm not interested in identifying this variation, but simply does the mean percent of sales vary between country (assume identical seasonality in all countries).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have the actual numbers, or just the percentages?

Comment: I have the actual numbers - but they vary wildly between stores (some store have ten times as many customers) - the relevant metric for comparison is percent.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do a statistical test? If you want to know whether stores in some countries purchase one product more often than other stores do, then why not simply calculate how often and be done with it? Now if instead you have a sample of stores for each country and you want to generalize to the countries, then that is a different question. But the answer depends on what kind of sample you have. This, however, doesn't seem to be the case here. You seem to have all the stores in a country.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not interested in identifying this variation, but simply does the mean percent of sales vary between country ... I have the actual numbers - but they vary wildly between stores (some store have ten times as many customers) - the relevant metric for comparison is percent.

Since the question you're asking is the percent between countries, and the absolute number of sales varies greatly between stores in the same country, perhaps you should consider working at the granularity not of store-sales by months, but of single sales.

Consider the case where some country has two stores, with figures that never vary from month to month. The first store services 1000 customers per month, out of which 200 make a sale, and the second store services 10000 customers per month, out of which 1000 make a sale. The country has an average sales rate of

$$
    \frac{200 + 1000}{1000 + 10000} \neq \frac{\frac{200}{1000} + \frac{1000}{10000}}{2}.
$$

Working in single-sale granularity is easy. Suppose there are $m$ countries, and country $i$ had a total of $c_i$ customers, out of which $s_i$ made sales ($s_i \leq c_i$). The null hypothesis, according to your question, is that the country does not affect sales. Under the null hypthesis, if $S_i$ is the random variable of the sales in country $i$, then

$$E[S_i] = c_i \frac {\sum_i s_i}{\sum_i c_i}.$$

In fact, $S_i$ has the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)

$$P(S_i = k) = 
\frac{{\sum_i s_i \choose k}{\sum_i c_i - \sum_i s_i \choose c_i - k}}{{\sum_i c_i \choose c_i}}.
$$

If $S_i \neq E[S_i]$ (which will almost certainly happen), you can use a summation of the above to see what is the p-value of the result (i.e., the probability of obtaining a result at least as far away from the expectation as this one).

As $m$ is small, it might pay to directly use here the [Bonferroni correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction). That is, multiply the p-value obtained per each country by $m$. If it is still smaller than some threshold, reject the null hypothesis.